# Creating Pivot table with existing spreadsheet using powershell

Tags: powershell

I have been working with the ImportExcel module and trying to figure out if it's what I need or not.

I want to take an existing spreadsheet, and create a pivot table from that spreadsheet.

I have tried the following

```
Export-Excel $path -Show -IncludePivotTable -PivotRows Provider Service Type -PivotData @{ Handles = "sum" }
```

This is not giving me anything.  Do I have to import my existing spreadsheet into powershell and then export it and make Pivot tables?

Also, I'm still just learning this stuff so take it easy on me :) and thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You do need to get something for `Export-Excel` to output. If it's a .xlsx already, you can use `Import-Excel` and then pipe it to `Export-Excel`

```
Import-Excel C:\examplefile.xlsx |
    Export-Excel $path -Show -IncludePivotTable -PivotRows Provider Service Type -PivotData @{ Handles = "sum" }
```

Comment: Export-Excel : The input object cannot be bound to any parameters for the command either because the command does not
take pipeline input or the input and its properties do not match any of the parameters that take pipeline input.

Comment: What does the output of just `Import-Excel C:\examplefile.xlsx` look like? Is your starting spreadsheet an xlsx?

Comment: It spits out the files in the powershell window but doesn't actually open the spreadsheet.

Comment: Also, yes, my starting spreadsheet is an xlsx file, and thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I have done the following trying some stuff out and it works, so basically I need to do the same thing but with an existing spreadsheet, grr, so close, any help again would be appreciated.

```
Function New-Person ($dept, $name, [double]$salary, [int]$yearsEmployeed) { 
New-Object PSObject  | 
    Add-Member -PassThru Noteproperty Dept $dept | 
    Add-Member -PassThru Noteproperty Name $name | 
    Add-Member -PassThru Noteproperty Salary $salary | 
    Add-Member -PassThru Noteproperty YearsEmployeed $yearsEmployeed  
} 

$( 
New-Person IT Doug 100 10 
New-Person IT John 200 5 
New-Person IT Tom 300 6  
New-Person IT Dick 400 7 


New-Person Sales Jane 1100 8  
New-Person Sales Tina 1200 9 
New-Person Sales Tammy 1300 11 
New-Person Sales Dawn 1400 12 

) | Export-Excel "C:\path" -Show -IncludePivotTable -PivotRows salary
```

Comment: Ok, I'm getting there, tried this and it worked, but when I use the -PivotRows option it errors out

    PS C:\windows\system32> Import-Csv     C:\Scripts\Flapper_Report_12_21_2016.csv | Export-Excel      C:\Scripts\teststuffspiv.xlsx
    -Show -IncludePivotTable

Comment: My guess would be issues with the formatting of the imported csv. Does the exported spreadsheet look right without the `-IncludePivotTable`?